# mozilla aframe drag release is treated as a click, is that a bug?

Tags: 3d, mozilla, aframe

I'm experimenting with AFrame JS framework and I noticed that when using mouse drag on desktop to rotate the scene, upon releasing the mouse button a click is triggered. That happens when cursor is pointing at an object.
Is that a bug or just a configuration thing? How can I switch that behavior off?
Thanks,

M

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame is focused on WebVR so the desktop drag/click is more a preview mode to check out experiences without needing a headset. The gaze cursor is geared for Cardboard VR not for mouse/keyboard.

If you want to design a 2D mouse/keyboard experience, I'd use Pointer Lock style controls like in Don's Universal Controls https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras

Comment: I was thinking how to answer the WebVR focus, took me a while. Some companies (including the one I'm working for) have interest in developing 3d/VR content, but see the headset/glasses requirement as a problem. It is essentially a hardware problem, not many people have access to VR headsets, but most people have 3d acceleration and flat screens. In my opinion focusing on AFrame as a 3d web technology would be more beneficial. It would increase the customer base and thus promote AFrame development and adoption. Just my 2 cents, AFrame is a great product and it's ease of use is very important.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We're willing to focus on the long term of WebVR and not worry about just getting users and "customers". People always free to extend A-Frame to do what they want.